# How to have a double-quoted parameter with spaces work with a PowerShell Start-Process command in a dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have this reg.exe PowerShell command I would like to run from a dockerfile:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'reg.exe' -ArgumentList 'add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Foo Bar" /v Version /t REG_DWORD /d 5 /f' -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru
```

This works if I run from within it's own PowerShell command.

I also have this in a dockerfile which works:

```
RUN $reg_process = Start-Process -FilePath 'reg.exe' -ArgumentList 'add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\FooBar /v Version /t REG_DWORD /d 5 /f' -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru; `
    if ($reg_process.ExitCode -ne 0) { `
        Write-Host \"reg.exe failed with exit code $($reg_process.ExitCode)\"; `
        exit 1; `
    }
```

I do have this toward the top of my dockerfile, which must stay there...

```
# escape=`

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
```

My goal is to get that RUN statement working when I change the key name to have a space in it (Foo Bar). I have tried every combination of escaping with backslash, back-ticks and double-quotes which I can possibly think of. Does anybody know how to run a command like this in a dockerfile?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to achieve my goal by doing a double `\"\"` for internal quotations and a single `\"` for external quotations. I thought that by escaping the quotations I would also need to escape the backslashes within the string, but guess not! I have not been able to find anywhere this is documented. I hope this helps somebody else in the future.

```
RUN $reg_process = Start-Process -FilePath 'reg.exe' -ArgumentList \"add \"\"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Foo Bar\"\" /v Version /t REG_DWORD /d 5 /f\" -NoNewWindow -Wait -PassThru; `
    if ($reg_process.ExitCode -ne 0) { `
        Write-Host \"PROCESS FAILED: reg.exe (Exit Code: $($reg_process.ExitCode))\"; `
        exit 1; `
    }
```